# ExtJS Singleton Function Not Returning Correctly

Tags: javascript, extjs, singleton

I have a ExtJS global function. I added a new value "isreadonly".

```
Ext.define('TestApp.classes.User', {
    singleton: true,

    constructor: function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
    },

    config: {
        username: 'username',
            userfirstname: 'John',
            userlastname: 'Doe',
        usergroup: '1234',
        userid: '1234',
            usertestid: '1234',
            permissions: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                  storeId: 'permissions',
                  autoLoad: false,
              fields: ['item_tag'],
                  proxy:      {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '/Test.cfc?method=getPermissions&username=1234&usergroup=1234',
                        timeout: 120000,
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'ROWS',
                    successProperty: 'SUCCESS',
                    totalProperty: 'TOTAL'                 
                        }
                  },
            listeners: {
                load: {
                    fn: function(store, records, successful, eOpts) {
                                    _TestApp.initData(this.storeId);
                              }
                }
            }                                          
            }),
            isreadonly: function() {
              var permissions = Ext.getStore('permissions');
              var hasPermission = permissions.findRecord('item_tag','btn_read_only');

              if (hasPermission !== null) {
                  return true;
              } else {
                  return false;
              }
          }
    }
});
```

I can refer to other values via TestApp.classes.User.getUsergroup() to retrieve get the value for UserGroup. However my new value "isreadonly" is always returning false when I call TestApp.classes.User.getIsreadonly().

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was approaching this the wrong way. The problem wasn't the function but my approach. Sorry for the confusion.